# Can't stop tomcat normally when I configure jmxremote

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

I added a `jmxremote` configuraiton in the catalina.bat:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9004 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

so that I could start jconsole to monitor the tomcat's performance.

But I got a problem that I couldn't stop tomcat normally through `$CATALINA_HOME\catalina.bat stop`, neither did `$CATALINA_HOME\shutdown.bat`

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do the logs indicate, if anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to monitor the java process, you need to add the following system properties to the command line:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

In the visualvm you just use the connection string host:9999.

However, sometimes the RMI listener listens to the wrong IP address, one which is inaccessible to the visualvm. Thanks to Pavel’s tip, I found a  way to overcome this is by adding the following parameters:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$(hostname)
-Djava.rmi.server.useLocalHostname=true
```

Now it works like a charm!

For completeness, I’d mention you can secure the connection to the JVM, either by requiring user/password or by using SSL. If you are interested, please see [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html).

Make sure that you put the definitions in a place only the start command sees, but not the shutdown. The reason or this is that the jmx remote create a listening socket, making the shutdown to listen to the same port if not configured properly.

Comment: thanks, I have the same problem as the author. I just added these properties to the JAVA_OPTS variable, which is used on a shutdown too I suppose? So you think it can be the cause of issue?

Comment: @javagirl if the shutdown tries to open a listening socket on an already bound socket, then it will fail. Make sure you don't add the JMX definition to the stop command

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Put the `jmxremote` setting in the **doStart**  block and it will be ok

Comment: Also - make sure that the JMX properties are in CATALINA_OPTS, not JAVA_OPTS

Comment: This answer is a perfect example why answers shouldn't consist only of a link - your link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed now

Comment: the blog link is not working.can you add the content in edit

Comment: David was right.Catalina_opts was not used in stop block.so putting it in Catalina_opts solved the problem.

Comment: The link is dead. Now this post is useless.

Comment: @rustyx  I've updated the post with the information

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Tomcat started successfully?

Usually you need to add this property before the other jmx properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html#Enabling_JMX_Remote

Answer (score 0):

Better to add these parameters to the CATALINA_OPTS in the file setenv.sh or setenv.bat

```
# JMX OPTIONS
CATALINA_OPT="$CATALINA_OPT "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
CATALINA_OPT="$CATALINA_OPT "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9012
CATALINA_OPT="$CATALINA_OPT "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
CATALINA_OPT="$CATALINA_OPT "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
CATALINA_OPT="$CATALINA_OPT "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```