# Unable to restart tomcat after enabling jmx remote connection

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

I wanted to remotely monitor my app running inside tomcat so I configured JMX remote connection inside setenv.sh file.

Following is my configuration.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<jmx_port> 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<jmx_port> 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<my_host_ip>".
```

**Note : This is only for test. I won't mind disabled ssl and authenticate = false in my configuration.**

I was able to connect to it using visualmv running on my local machine. The problem started when I tried to restart the tomcat. On shutdown process tomcat successfully shutdown but port on which jmx was running was still active and usable by JMX. So on tomcat start, it complained  **already in use** hence failing tomcat startup.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199630/cant-stop-tomcat-normally-when-i-configure-jmxremote

Comment: @weizenkeimhugo I already had a look on same post. The link  given in accepted answer is broken. Also most of the answers suggest to use CATALINE_OPTS instead of JAVA_OPTS and I am already using CATALINA_OPTS.

I know if I use JAVA_OPTS, then there would be issues while tomcat shutdown. But I have issues while starting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same port for jmxremote.port and jmxremote.rmi.port ? If so, they need to be different. One is the service listener, the other is the rmi registry.

Comment: Yes I am using the same port number for both. Actually I did not want to expose too many ports of my instances to outside world. But anyway I will give it try.

Comment: You can't bind two listeners to one port.